# Capybara unable to select radio button in data tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I have a bit of an issue, im trying to select a radio button in a data-tables data. Im able to filter the single data-tables row down to one so it's the only one appearing on the page...but i've tried `page.choose`, `page.find(<xpath>)`, `page.find(<css>)`, i've also tried doing all the previous within a certain css selection and I can't quite figure out what's left to try.

The relevant HTML is here, unfortunately as this is a work item I can't post everything. however I AM able to click on the label if I specify the id via:

`find(:xpath, "//label[@for='approve_row_5']").click` however this doesn't actually seem to 'select' the radio button. I've also tried doing a wait after I filter the data-table results

anyways, here is the HTML for the 2 radio buttons after the row has been filtered (the radio buttons reside in a column)

```
<td class=" align-middle">
        <div class="radio">
          <input type="radio" name="approve_deny_row_5" id="approve_deny_row_5_approve" value="person_approve" data-ui-verify-key="test_approve" data-ui-verify-title="2017-07-13 14:59:46 -0400">
          <label for="approve_deny_row_5_approve">
            <span>Approve</span>
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="radio">
          <input type="radio" name="approve_deny_row_5" id="approve_deny_row_5_deny" value="person_deny" data-ui-verify-key="test_deny" data-ui-verify-title="2017-07-13 14:59:46 -0400" data-ui-verify-url="/irrelevant/stuff">
          <label for="approve_deny_row_5_deny">
            <span>Deny</span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </td>
```

I thought about just finding the span by the text and clicking it, which passes....but doesn't actually select the radio button. Also I tried searching by the specific value selector as well via a `find('input[value="test_approve"]').click` but that had no luck either

Any ideas?

Comment: There is no `input` element with `value` attribute that is equal to `"test_approve"`, but `value="person_approve"` at least on provided piece of `HTML`. Did you try `find('input[value="person_approve"]').click` or `find('input[data-ui-verify-key="test_approve"]').click` ?

Comment: Assuming the `input` elements are actually visible on the page then `choose("approve_deny_row_5_approve")` and `choose("approve_deny_row_5_deny")` should select one or the other radio button (As should `choose("Approve")` and `choose("Deny") as long as you're scoped to the row)- what error exactly do they produce?

Comment: @Andersson that was just a mis-type, i changed some values and forgot to change that. 

@ThomasWalpole Unfortunately choose('Approve') does not work and will result in `Capybara::ElementNotFound:Unable to find radio button "Approve"` same goes for using the ID. Perhaps it's a scoping issue, as I use a filter elsewhere in the page beforehand (Which is a text form).

Comment: @msmith1114 You can try `choose('Approve', allow_label_click: true)` in case the radio input isn't actually visible on the page.  If that also gives a Capybara::ElementNotFound then you definitely have a scoping issue and you'll need to show the actual test code you're using.  Any company that won't allow test code to be posted publically really needs to re-evaluate their policies.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole That actually does seem to not fail, although I can tell the radio button isn't being selected (as a modal pops up after).  When you say scoping issue what exactly do you mean? Is it because I might be doing a `fill_in` on another part of the page, the focus is maybe not in the correct area?

Comment: @msmith1114 Scoping issue would be if you were in a `within` block that didn't contain the radio buttons.  However, the fact that it doesn't fail with the `:allow_label_click` option means your radio buttons are within scope but are not actually visible on the page and Capybara is instead clicking on the label.  That an expected modal doesn't pop up tends to indicate that the JS on the page is broken/suboptimal UI.  Does it pop up when you manually click on the label?  If not you need to get the devs to fix it, or figure out exactly what element is visible on the page that needs to be clicked.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole it is clickable and the radio button itself does appear when doing the same thing manually (the radio button appears when I watch the chrome selenium browser do it's thing too) thats why my mind is boggled on this one.

Comment: What do you mean the "radio button" appears -- you said a modal should appear ?  Does the modal appear when you manually click on the label text ?  If not you're going to have to show the test code and more clearly explain how exactly it's not doing what you want.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole So I meant the radio button itself I can see on the page, but a modal appears (In normal use) AFTER clicking the radio button. I noticed when I used the code above (to click the label) the radio button is not selected (with the inner dot filled like radio buttons are after selection) and no modal pops up.

Comment: @msmith1114 Then you need to look at/inspect the page source and figure out what elements the visible radio buttons actually are -  they are not the input elements you show in your question - those are not actually visible on the page.  Also, I'm not clear -- does the modal appear when you manually click on the label text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the actual radio inputs are visible on the page (and not hidden to allow for styling) the methods that should work for this are

```
choose("Approve")
choose("Deny")
```

or

```
choose("approve_deny_row_5_approve")
choose("approve_deny_row_5_deny")
```

If those tell you they can't find the elements then it's most likely the input elements are actually hidden (for styling reasons) and you should be able to use the

```
choose('Approve', allow_label_click: true)
```

which will click on the label element associated with the input rather than the input element.  That should produce the same result (setting the radio button) unless the behavior you're looking for is based on JS looking for a click on a very specific element (rather than the change event on the input).  If that happens to be the case then you need to figure out exactly what element the JS is looking for clicks on, or fix the JS to behave in a more intuitive manner.

Comment: So this is interesting, I CAN click the label and get the modal to appear but it takes 2 clicks, this only happens if i've just typed in the filter (a text box). So im guessing since the focus is on the text box that is what causes the issue. For instance if I type in the text box then click out of it anywhere else a single click on the label will make the radio button be selected appropriately. 

In code I can do:
`choose('Approve', allow_label_click: true)`

`choose('Approve', allow_label_click: true)` (Put it twice)

and it works...surely there is a less hacky way though.

Comment: @msmith1114  Does it work with only one click on the label when done manually. ie if the user does EXACTLY the actions you're telling Capybara to do, (fill in a specific field, then one click on the label, etc) does the modal show up ??

Comment: No it doesn't (sorry thats what I was trying to explain). If I fill in the text box, then click the label it won't work, it's not until I click it again that it works.

If I click anywhere else on the page after filling in the text box then doing a single click on the label DOES work. (Referring to doing this manually and NOT with Capybara). So in Capybara I was able to make it work by just doing the `choose('Approve', allow_label_click: true)` twice. Although that's obviously sort of hacky and messy and I was saying there must be some other way that's cleaner.

Comment: @msmith1114 Well if it doesn't work manually, then it's not the fault of Capybara -- If that's what would happen to a user you should fix the page so that whatever JS is handling the clicks doesn't ignore the first click and then you wouldn't have to try and hack around it with Capybara either.

Comment: That's correct for sure. I'll see if were able to make JS changes. I suppose worst case scenario I could always click somewhere outside the text box with Capybara and then click...but like we both said it's hacky at best.

Comment: @msmith1114 Look at that -- Capybara identifying a usability issue :)

Comment: I guess it did it's intended purpose! haha.